# Find Max Date for multiple records in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Say I have a query similar to this: select NodeId, Max(LastReported) as LatestRecord from NodeInfo where NodeId in (1, 3, 5) Group By NodeId. This table would have multiple records from each node and a date corresponding to that record.

How in PowerBI would I replicate this query?

Comment: Sorry, please clarify: do you want to replicate this in the dataset itself, or via a DAX calculation?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with Get Data / From SQL Server (or Recent Sources if you have already made a connection to your SQL server), then select your NodeInfo table and choose Edit.

In the Edit Queries window, first filter NodeId to 1, 3 or 5.  Then hit the Group By button. Specify NodeId as the Group By column and a Max Operation on the  LastReported column.